# Trying to output the length of a string using strlen() through a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, assignment-operator, strlen

I am trying to output the length of a string using strlen(). But I want to do it through a pointer.

Here's what I tried:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[]="wel";
    int *p;
    p=&a;
    printf("%d\n",strlen(*p));
}
```

The image shows the error I am getting while compiling:[image]

Then made this change in the code declaration of *p to *p[]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[]="wel";
    int *p[];
    p=&a;
    printf("%d\n",strlen(*p));
}
```

But then I am getting an error "storage size of 'p' isn't known."
What am I still missing?

Comment: What made you use an `int*` instead of a `char*`? It should be `char *p; p = a; printf("%zu\n", strlen(p));;`

Comment: You don't need the variable `p`, its just `strlen(a)`

Comment: @jvx8ss _"But I want to do it through a pointer"_

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your suggested changes worked! Thanks. And I am sorry but aren't pointers used to store addresses which are in integer? And also p stores address of a so shouldn't be p=&a?

Comment: @PankitShah: Pointers store addresses as *pointers*. You can perform some int-like manipulations with them, but the sizes don't reliably match (`int` is usually 4 bytes, and pointers are larger on 64 bit systems), and the type of what it points to is unrelated to its pointerness. `p = a;` (or equivalently, `p = &a[0];`) is correct, because arrays degrade to pointers to their first element; technically, `&a` is getting a pointer to `arr[4]` (so incrementing it would move the pointer four bytes, not one), but in practice, most compilers allow that mild eccentricity.

Comment: Blech, noticed it too late: Minor correction: `&a` is getting a pointer to `char[4]` (it's a pointer to "units" arrays of four characters a piece).

Answer (score 2):

Except in a couple of limited circumstances (noteably `sizeof`), an array degrades into a pointer to its first element when used. So this is what you need:

```c
char *p = a;   // Same as `p = &(a[0])`
printf( "%zu\n", strlen( p ) );
```

Note that `strlen` returns a `size_t`, and `%zu` is the correct format specifier for that.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the array `a` initialized with a string literal

```
char a[]="wel";
```

is equivalent to

```
char a[4]="wel";
```

So the expression `&a`  has the type `char ( * )[4]` but the pointer `p` has the type `int *`

```
int *p;
```

and there is no implicit conversion between the pointer types.

And again the function `strlen` expects a pointer of the type `char *` but you are passing an expression of the type `int`

```
printf("%d\n",strlen(*p));
```

Also the return type of the function `strlen` is `size_t`. So at least you have to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d` in the call of `printf`.

It seems what you mean is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char a[] = "wel";
    char *p;

    p = a;

    printf( "%zu\n", strlen( p ) );
}
```

In this assignment statement

```
p = a;
```

the array `a` used in the right hand side expression is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element of the type `char *`.

As for the second program then you declared an array of pointers without specifying the number of elements

```
int *p[];
```

Such a declaration is invalid.

And moreover arrays do not have the assignment operator that you are trying to use

```
p=&a;
```

So the second program in whole does not make sense.

If you want to use the expression `&a` as an initializer then the pointer `p` has to be declared like

```
char ( *p )[4];
```

or

```
char ( *p )[sizeof( a )];
```

In this case the program can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char a[] = "wel";
    char ( *p )[sizeof( a )];

    p = &a;

    printf( "%zu\n", strlen( *p ) );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

p is not a string, it is the pointer to type int.
Why just not use

```
printf("%d\n",strlen(a));
```

Then use

```
char a[4]="wel";
```

Comment: OP stated _"But I want to do it through a pointer"_ so I don't think this answer helps.

Comment: Also, that's the wrong format specifier. So not only does it not answer the question, it's wrong.

Comment: @Peter Irich Instead of char a[4]="wel"; it is better to write char a[]="wel";

Comment: I Very don't like this construction and never use it: char *[];